# Where is the actual risk magazine?

Tags: research

On Risk.net I can see every issue and underneath each, there's just a bunch of links to articles on risk.net.

See picture below.

[image]

Okay great, but where is the actual magazine? Isn't that supposed to be an actual, unified magazine with an intro/outro by the editor and all that type of stuff? You know, like an actual journal? Or is "Risk Magazine" really just a bunch of random links to articles from Risk.net over the past month???

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it isn't a question based Quant Finance problem.

Comment: and yet there's several questions on this site inquiring about journals.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risk_(magazine)